# Read attribute value from XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to transform and filter an xml file with xsl, but I have a problem. If I try to get the value of an attribute from a node, the variable `var_value` is also a node. In my opinion is this the reason why I cannot compare the `var_value` with any string. Am I right?

XML File:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListItemsResponse>
      <GetListItemsResult>
        <listitems xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
          <rs:data ItemCount="1">
            <z:row ows_ID="1" ows_Status0="Active" ows_Priority="3" ows_Criticality="Critical" />
          </rs:data>
        </listitems>
      </GetListItemsResult>
    </GetListItemsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="ar_Fields">
    <Field>ows_Status0</Field>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/" name="TransformFields">
<xsl:param name="param_Attribute"/><xsl:variable name="var_EmptyDate" select="'1900-01-01 00:00:00'"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="//*['z:row']/@*">
        <xsl:variable name="var_Name" select="name()"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var_Value"><xsl:value-of select="string(.)"></xsl:value-of></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="$ar_Fields">
            <xsl:if test="not($var_EmptyDate=$var_Value) and ($var_Name=$ar_Fields/.)">
                <xsl:call-template name="CreateElement">
                    <xsl:with-param name="param_Name" select="$var_Name"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="param_Value" select="$var_Value"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="CreateElement">
    ...
 </xsl:template>
```

The result should look like this:`<Field Name="Status0">Active</Field>`

Comment: Do you get an error with your comparison or why do you say you "cannot compare the var_value with any string"? Which error do you get? What is `//*['z:row']` supposed to select? A non-empty string like `'z:row'` will make the predicate true in any case.

Comment: No I don't get an error, but if I try to compare the node with an defined string, e.g. var_value is a node set with the content (Status0,Active) then `<xsl:if test="$var_Value='Active'">` returns false.

Comment: Can you show your full expected output document?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to follow your code. Couldn't this be simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="z">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="ar_Fields">
    <Field>ows_Status0</Field>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Field Name="Status0">
        <xsl:value-of select="//z:row/@*[name()=$ar_Fields/Field]"/>
    </Field>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to create a node for each attribute of z:row. It should looks like this: `<Field name="AttributeName">AttributeValue</Field>`. That works, but I cannot check if the value is empty.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow. Creating a node for each attribute of z:row is very easy. What does this has to with the variable? And what do you mean by "check if the value is empty"? That too is easy - but what do you want to happen as the result? Also, in your example z:row has 4 attributes, but your result has only one node.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your bug is in the line

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*['z:row']/@*">
```

I don't know what you intended this to do, but the predicate `['z:row']` is useless - the effective boolean value of the string `'z:row'` is true. Perhaps you meant the predicate to be `[self::z:row]`? But in that case why didn't you write `select="//z:row/@*"`?

In any case, your theory is incorrect. Comparing a node with a string works fine (the node is implicitly atomized).